How large can a git repository on Azure DevOps get?
We have a GIT with GIT-LFS mono repository where the whole codebase size in GIT (using git-sizer) shows (see table below, please note the git-sizer does not show the git-lfs objects).
| Name                         | Value     | Level of concern               |
| ---------------------------- | --------- | ------------------------------ |
| Biggest objects              |           |                                |
| * Trees                      |           |                                |
|   * Maximum entries      [1] |  1.23 k   | *                              |
| * Blobs                      |           |                                |
|   * Maximum size         [2] |   900 MiB | !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! |
|                              |           |                                |
| Biggest checkouts            |           |                                |
| * Number of directories  [3] |  5.00 k   | **                             |
| * Maximum path depth     [4] |    19     | *                              |
| * Maximum path length    [5] |   222 B   | **                             |
| * Number of files        [3] |   102 k   | **                             |
| * Total size of files    [6] |  2.42 GiB | **                             |

The problem is that we have very large datasets for integration and datatest as well as unit-tests, where the unit-test data can start from a few Kilobytes to maybe a 1GB.
Currently we are hosting this data on a seperate network drive which requires our build-agents to have access to this in-house network drive. This prevents us to use AzureDevOps hosted build-agents.
Additionally, the problem is that the network drive is not in-sync with the git-repo so we needed to esatblish some sort of file versioning which every now and then goes wrong.
The idea now is to put the data in our git repo where the binary files are in GIT-LFS.
The problem is that if the data is in GIT-LFS the cloning takes maybe forever and I have no experience what this means for fetch/pull/push in general.
We also had a look at GIT-scalar but I haven't found out what git-scalar exactly does and how it can help us. I was seeing GIT-scalar more as OneDrive solution, where the data is downloaded on demand.
The other question is if a Azure repo can grow unlimited. I was reading something around 250GB limit.
Is there any experience in this of how this can be done?

There is a limit of 250 GB in Azure repo. According to Git limits,

Repositories should be no larger than 250 GB.


If you need to store large files, consider using Git LFS (Large File Storage), which is designed to handle large files efficiently by storing them outside the main repository and only keeping references to them within the repository. This approach helps maintain the performance and manageability of your Git repository.

For "The problem is that if the data is in GIT-LFS the cloning takes maybe forever ",
If you use MS-hosted agents, you will get a new agent each time you run the pipeline. If your files are large, whether they are in GIT-LFS or not, the checkout time will increase as the files get larger. In Azure pipeline, you can use checkout task to checkout the large file via the lfs parameter.
steps:
- checkout: string # Required as first property. Configures checkout for the specified repository.
  clean: true | false # If true, run git clean -ffdx followed by git reset --hard HEAD before fetching.
  fetchDepth: string # Depth of Git graph to fetch.
  fetchFilter: string # Filter Git history.
  fetchTags: string # Set to 'true' to sync tags when fetching the repo, or 'false' to not sync tags. See remarks for the default behavior.
  lfs: string # Set to 'true' to download Git-LFS files. Default is not to download them.
  persistCredentials: string # Set to 'true' to leave the OAuth token in the Git config after the initial fetch. The default is not to leave it.
  submodules: string # Set to 'true' for a single level of submodules or 'recursive' to get submodules of submodules. Default is not to fetch submodules.
  path: string # Where to put the repository. The root directory is $(Pipeline.Workspace).
  workspaceRepo: true | false # When true, use the repository root directory as the default working directory for the pipeline. The default is false.
  condition: string # Evaluate this condition expression to determine whether to run this task.
  continueOnError: boolean # Continue running even on failure?
  displayName: string # Human-readable name for the task.
  target: string | target # Environment in which to run this task.
  enabled: boolean # Run this task when the job runs?
  env: # Variables to map into the process's environment.
    string: string # Name/value pairs
  name: string # ID of the step.
  timeoutInMinutes: string # Time to wait for this task to complete before the server kills it.
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: string # Number of retries if the task fails.

lfs : Set to 'true' to download Git-LFS files. Default is not to download them.
For "and I have no experience what this means for fetch/pull/push in general."
It's suggested that you see git-lfs and this wiki to understand GIT-LFS.
Besides, see Manage and store large files in Git for more info about managing large file in Azure repo.

Thanks for the hint. For large files we already using git-lfs. As you said this is all or nothing even if you don't need it for units tests. Therefore the question is also when using git-scalar if the required data is downloaded on demand?

One feature of git scalar is to partially clone. By default, Scalar reduces your working directory to only the files at the root of the repository. You can use git sparse-checkout set to set the directory list for your sparse-checkout. Then only your target files/folder will be downloaded. See this doc for the details.

Thanks for the explanation. I know about the sparse checkout,  but the sparse checkout is something that I need to do manually vai commandline. Is if git scalara is activated is it helping me in downloading the files automatically when they are required? I couldn't see this from the docs.

"Is if git scalara is activated is it helping me in downloading the files automatically when they are required?"- If you use git scalar on your local machine or a self-hosted agent this might work (you can verify this on your side, I haven't tested it), but if you use an MS-hosted agent I'm afraid it doesn't work. Since you get a brand new agent every time you run a pipeline.

Alright. I agree that this might not work on MS hosted-agents, but this would be OK.
I will aceept this as an asnwer.
